# Fusion table Oauth issues in python-google-api service account

Tags: oauth, google-fusion-tables, google-api-python-client

I am migrating from the SQL api to the new API v1 for google fusion tables. I'm using the google api python library. I've gone through the migration steps but am still having issues with oauth. I need to do a service account authentication and have set one up. I modeled my authentication based on the sample given here: http://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/source/browse/samples/service_account/tasks.py

Here is my code:

```
# Read in private key                                                                                                                                                        
f = file(KEY_FILE,'rb')
key = f.read()
f.close()

# Create an httplib2.Http object to handle our HTTP requests and authorize it                                                                                                
creds = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(API_EMAIL, key,   
    scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fusiontables')
http = httplib2.Http()
http = creds.authorize(http)

print vars(http.credentials)
service = build("fusiontables", "v1", http=http)

result = service.query().sql(sql="SELECT rowid, Title FROM "+TABLE_ID+" WHERE
ID="+str(id)).execute()

response = service.query().sql(sql="DELETE FROM "+TABLE_ID+" WHERE 
ROWID='"+result["rows"][0][0]+"'").execute()
```

The select statement works but then the delete statement I get a 403 Forbidden error. The print statement shows empty credentials.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test_oauth.py", line 36, in <module>
response = service.query().sql(sql="DELETE FROM "+TABLE_ID+" WHERE
ROWID='"+result["rows"][0][0]+"'").execute()
File "/lib/google-api/oauth2client/util.py", line 120, in positional_wrapper
return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
File "/lib/google-api/apiclient/http.py", line 680, in execute
raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
apiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting
https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query
alt=json&sql=DELETE+FROM+xxxx+WHERE+ROWID%3D%27239601%27 returned "Forbidden">
```

I'm able to run these statements from the API explorer no problem. Any help appreciated, thank you!!

Comment: Does your Service Account user have edit permission on the table? You need to explicitly add the service account to the table you want to access using the service account e-mail address (see the API console).

Comment: That was it!! Totally forgot about that. I added the developer service account email to the fusion table and that did the trick. Thank you Odi :)